# Syntax explanation using typedef

Tags: c++

I want to understand why **FAR** is used in the below **typedef** syntax?

```
#define FAR
//some other instructions
//.....
//.....

typedef struct tagDEVICE_BUFFER_W
{
 ....
 ....
}DEVICE_BUFFER_W;

typedef DEVICE_BUFFER_W FAR * LPDEVICE_BUFFER_W; //Why FAR is used here?
```

What if I dont use **FAR** as mentioned below? Will it make any difference?

```
typedef DEVICE_BUFFER_W * LPDEVICE_BUFFER_W;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's legacy from the olden days. 16-bit Windows code had near and far pointers. I think it was to distinguish between inter-segment and intra-segment addressing, but the memory has faded (a lot).

Comment: Back in the old days making games for DOS with Borland C++ I remember near, far, and I think huge pointers which did some sort of EMM/EMS magic.  Of course, once we switched to the flat memory model with Watcom all that went away.

Answer (score 3):

I don't actually know what a far pointer is, so I'm just going to point you to Wikipedia. As Marcelo has said though, it appears to be outdated and a legacy technology/technique.

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far_pointer) for the Wikipedia article.

Also, taken from a [programming forum](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/73103) (this links to a daniweb thread):

> In the old days of the 80286, there were near (16-bit) and far (16:16 = 20/24 bits) pointers. Memory was divided into segments of 64k bytes (16-bits) because of the 16-bit nature of the x86. The address bus supported 20 to 24-bits (1-16MB), so in order to address the larger area, segment registers were combined with 16-bit pointers to form the complete address. This architecture still exists on today's Pentiums, but it has become a non-issue. Windows uses a "flat" memory model where all segments point to the same place and instead of 16-bit offsets, there are 32-bit offsets. The FAR keyword has become unnecessary in modern x86 software.

Answer (score 1):

It might not make a difference for this particular implementation but on a different operating system or architecture they can use it to define extra information. In this case it's probably used for [far pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far_pointer):

```
#define FAR far
```